# Pass model from strongly typed view back to a controller action - mvc2 VB.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

Here's what I have. I have an MVC application where all the data is tied together by VisitDate table in my database. The home page is a strongly typed view of type VisitDate, all it does is pull up some simple data. Now, here's where I'm having a problemo. I need a link that passes the current model in the view back to a seperate controller action so I can render a different page with different data.

Here are my two controller actions. I'm going from News.aspx to FrontPage.aspx and hopefully passing SchoolVisit.

```
Function News(ByVal SchoolVisit As SchoolVisitDate) As ActionResult

    Dim db As New NewsData.NewsDB
    Dim repos As New NewsRepository

    Dim _classId As Integer
    _classId = (From a In db.SchoolClasses Where a.VisitDateID = SchoolVisit.VisitDateID Select a.ClassID).Single()

    ViewData("VisitDate") = FormatDateTime(SchoolVisit.VisitDate, vbShortDate)

    ViewData("Staff") = repos.GetStaff(_classId)
    ViewData("StockArticles") = From a In db.StockArticles Select a

    ViewData("Articles") = repos.GetArticles(_classId)

    Return View()
End Function

Function FrontPage(ByVal SchoolVisit As SchoolVisitDate) As ActionResult

    Dim repos As New NewsRepository
    Dim _VisitDateID As Integer

    _VisitDateID = SchoolVisit.VisitDateID

    ViewData("Editorial") = repos.GetEditorial(_VisitDateID)
    Return View()
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Html.ActionLink can be of help

Comment: I've been messing with that and can't seem to get the syntax right.
<%: Html.ActionLink("Page", "FrontPage", "Home", New With {.VisitDate = Model})%>
This passes back a route value of ?Length=4

Comment: you will have to pass model data as named parameter e.g. <%: Html.ActionLink("Page", "FrontPage", "Home", visitDate=Model.VisitDate})%>

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you have to do:

1. You should make the News view strongly typed for SchoolVisitDate.
2. Have a form that submits the strongly typed SchoolVisitDate stuff post back to controller
3. Add a Post method to your controller
4. Have that post method redirect to the FrontPage view.

Comment: This would work, however, the link is in the menu and I don't feel like fudging css to make the submit button look like a text link :/

Comment: I'm guessing you're coming over from WebForms... MVC is very helpful if you buy into it. Your code looks Webforms-esque and you won't really leverage the power of it this way.

Comment: You want to use Strongly typed models the vast majority of the time, http-post when you need to send stuff back allowing user feedback, http-get with hidden id references when if you don't.